# Porting a shell script from Solaris to Linux

Tags: linux, shell, solaris, rhel5

This should be pretty straightforward, but am not sure what it is complaining about.

```
type=${1-"-Debug"};
version=${2-"-0"};
echo "We are going to be building eValuate in build mode: " $type
if [[ $version = -1 ]]
  then
  echo "We are going to be building eValuate with omniORB-4.1.4"
  else
  echo "We are going to be building eValuate with omniORB-4.0.4"
fi
if [ $PLATFORM = "HPUX" ]
then
    if [ $type = -release ]
    then
      export MAKEFILE_MAIN=$PWD/common/makefile/makefile.hp
      export MAKEFILE_DEFS=$PWD/common/makefile/makefile.hp.rls
      shift
    else
      export MAKEFILE_MAIN=$PWD/common/makefile/makefile.hp
      export MAKEFILE_DEFS=$MAKEFILE_MAIN
    fi

    elif [ $PLATFORM = "AIX" ]
    then
       mv $PWD/Calculations/CalculationSTD/makefileAIX $PWD/Calculations/CalculationSTD/makefile
       mv $PWD/Calculations/CalculationSTD/StandardCalculationAIX.cpp     $PWD/Calculations/CalculationSTD/StandardCalculation.cpp
       rm -r $PWD/Calculations/CalculationSTD/Carleton
       if [ $type = -release ]
       then
         export MAKEFILE_MAIN=$PWD/common/makefile/makefile.aix
         export MAKEFILE_DEFS=$PWD/common/makefile/makefile.aix.rls
         shift
      else
     export MAKEFILE_MAIN=$PWD/common/makefile/makefile.aix
     export MAKEFILE_DEFS=$MAKEFILE_MAIN
      fi
  fi
```

This seems to work fine on Solaris and AIX, but on Linux, I get this error messages:

```
   : command not found 1:
   : command not found 2:
   We are going to be building eValuate in build mode:  -release
   ./setpath.sh1: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
   '/setpath.sh1: line 22: `       elif [ $PLATFORM = "AIX" ]
```

Why does it not like the elif? Or, is it complaining about something else?

Comment: Does the script have a proper shebang line?  If not, does adding `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning help?  (Though your syntax is not proper Bourne shell.  All the more reason to explicitly declare it as a `#!/bin/bash` script.)

Comment: I ran the script from bash, sh, ksh prompts, but I still get the same errors

Comment: Try to write "elif [ $PLATFORM = "AIX" ]" (single squeare brackets)

Comment: the code was written wrong, I have updated the code

Comment: Also be consistent - or use [ cond ] or [[ cond ]]. In later you should use "==" instead of "=".

Comment: Maybe remove `el` in `elif`? At least this complaint is obvious....

Comment: how else will I implement multiple else if?

Comment: Is `$PLATFORM` defined? If not, then `$PLATFORM` will expand to an empty string, and `elif [ $PLATFORM = "AIX" ]` will be a syntax error. You should at least change it to `elif [ "$PLATFORM" = "AIX" ]`. And your indentation is inconsistent.

Comment: *"the code was written wrong, I have updated the code"* -- Do you mean that the code you posted didn't match the code that had the problem? If so, then updating it is fine. But don't update the code in the question *to correct the problem you're asking about*; that would make the question useless.

Comment: I just copy pasted your script and it runs without any warnings. I've only replaces `[ cond ]` with `[[ cond ]]` and `=` with `-eq`. Sorry, but without being able to reproduce it, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer finally, it is thanks to something completely random, something to do with format:

I had transferred the file over from my windows machine, and I guess Linux is just a bitch that can't handle it. Solaris and AIX do just fine.

Used this command.
dos2unix *.sh